# how to convert an array into a json array objects

Tags: angular, typescript2.0, kendo-ui-angular2

I have an array say

```
var a = ['N','Normal','S','Severe','C','Confidential']
```

I need the output format like below,

```
[{code:'N',description:'Normal'},
 {code:'S',description:'Severe'},
 {code:'C',description:'Confidential'}
]
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: please let me know your array pattern is forever like 

var a = ['N','Normal','S','Severe','C','Confidential']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as follows:

```js
const array = ['N', 'Normal', 'S', 'Severe', 'C', 'Confidential'];
const object = array.reduce((result, value, i) => {
  i % 2 || result.push({code: value, description: array[i + 1]});
  return result;
}, []);

console.log(object);
```